# Can't get Video ID after uploading using Direct-Upload to Youtube

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube, youtube-api

I am using direct-upload method to upload video to youtube. Video successfully uploads but i can't get the video id after upload process finished.

```
try {
  $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
$v_id = $newEntry->getVideoId();
  mysql_query("UPDATE `mytable` SET youtube_video_id = '$v_id' WHERE ID = '$tid'");
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
  echo $httpException->getRawResponseBody();
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

this `$v_id` is returning EMPTY after upload.

anyone knows how to get the video id properly ?

Thanks

EDIT:

I Found the problem. It was all about mysql server. it has gone away everytime when i want to insert youtube video ID. I just did a mysql_ping and it solved.

Comment: Can you post an example $uploadUrl?

Comment: $uploadUrl = 'http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads';

Comment: Have you seen this? http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_checking_video_status.html#Check_Upload_Status

Comment: @Peter i checked it now but i don't know how to use it actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the problem. It was all about mysql server. it has gone away everytime when i want to insert youtube video ID. I just did a mysql_ping and it solved.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the case that the video is still being processed by Youtube and it has not assigned the video an ID yet. First we need to check the status of the video before querying it for info. Try the following

```
$state = $newEntry->getVideoState();

if ($state) {
  echo 'Upload video ID is ' . $newEntry->getVideoId();
  } else {
    echo "Not able to retrieve the video status information yet. " . 
      "Please try again later.\n";
}
```

Additionally, if that doesn't work, please provide more debug info like output of  var_dump($newEntry) after the submission.